# Trace class operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

There is a notion of [trace class operator in a Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class).

Is there a notion of trace class operator in arbitrary Banach space? locally convex space?

A reference will be helpful.

Comment: I think Grothendieck’s Nuclear Operators (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_operator) might be what you are looking for.